# Autoresize mask - pin top left corner of UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, autoresizingmask

The X is an image view, with parent UIScrollView. The X content mode is set to `Aspect Fit`.

## 4 inch

```
______
|    |
|    | 
|X   |
|____|
```

When I switch between 4 inch to 3.5 inch display I want X to be pinned in the top left corner. Therefore, to my understanding I try to set the autoresize masks as following:

[image]

Now what happens instead, is that the X is pushed more to the centre. I would assume this is due to the fact that Aspect Fit tries to preserve ratio.

## 3.5 inch

```
______
|    |
| X  | 
|____|
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

## Edit after comments

In Storyboard/Interface Builder the VC Custom class is set to `ContactVC`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`. It has one UIScrollview and an UIImageView subview created in IB, as already explained above. . In my `ContactVC.m` I override `didLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews` but they are not getting called.

```
@implementation ContactViewController

-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    UIViewAutoresizing mask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [someImageView setAutoresizingMask:mask];
}

-(void) viewLayoutSubviews {
    UIViewAutoresizing mask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [someImageView setAutoresizingMask:mask];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your autoresize mask is overridden later, after the view has been created with the autoresize mask from the xib.

Try to set your autoresize mask in `layoutSubviews`, or maybe in the view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Everything is done in Interface Builder. However, I tried in viewDidLoad with this mask and it didn't work: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

Comment: I tried that to no avail. Debugger doesn't step into any of the methods either.

Comment: You actually subclassed your scroll view? If not, how did you "try out" overriding `layoutSubviews`? If these methods are not called, something is seriously flawed...

Comment: It is a subclass of UIViewController. I have updated my question with further explanation.

Comment: I am drawing the conclusion that this is not possible if the content mode is set to Aspect Fit. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW2

Comment: Are you sure you implemented `viewDiDLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: I am now, because I thought the method signature was didLayoutSubviews and not viewDidLayoutSubviews, please see my edited question. Is the mask set correctly?

Comment: I think you need to add `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`.

Comment: is there anything that needs to be turned off in Storyboard? It doesn't have any effect - same result. I am sure that the debugger steps into those methods.